# Is it possible to locally connect with python to an RDS instance in a VPC?

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have an RDS (Postgres) instance operational in a VPC. I have successfully configured lambda functions to connect, but I would like to be able to connect locally from my computer. Is this something that is possible? I have read about using an EC2 bastion host, but I would really like to just be able to run it without any additional architecture.

I've tried modifying this code from a different SO answer to no avail:

```
import psycopg2
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import time

with SSHTunnelForwarder(
         ('database host', 22),
         ssh_password="password",
         ssh_username="user",
         remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 5432)) as server:

    conn = psycopg2.connect(database="db",port=server.local_bind_port)
    curs = conn.cursor()
    sql = "select * from tableA limit 10;"
    curs.execute(sql)
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    print(rows)
```

Comment: The RDS host wouldn't be running SSH, so that won't help. You can allow your current IP address in the RDS security group (if it's publicly addressable) though, or maybe add a NAT gateway.

Comment: @AKX a NAT gateway is only for outbound connections, it would not help in this instance.

Comment: Ah, my bad on that point then.

Comment: The whole point of the bastion host is to provide SSH access to the VPC, without the bastion host you can't use the SSHTunnel method you are attempting. You will either need to add a bastion host, or set "publicly accessible" to `true` on the RDS instance.

Comment: So bastion host it is, I suppose. This is a production database that cannot be publicly accessible. We manage our infra with convox and so I usually just run convox proxy command to access it. Not sure how to do the equivalent here

Comment: The alternative to a Bastion would be to use [AWS Client VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/12/introducing-aws-client-vpn-to-securely-access-aws-and-on-premises-resources/).